# 12.04 Stability, Compatibility and Operational Problems

Tags: 12.04, fglrx, ati, compatibility

Today I installed Ubuntu 12.04 a full 5 times. But the continuous output of nonsense errors.

First, let me give hardware information;

> HP Compaq 6735s Laptop;

- Amd Trion X2 Mobile 64Bit Precessor (2.2 ghz)
- 4 Gb Ram
- 512 MB Ati Mobility Radeon HD 3200 GPU

All the installation attempts, the ATI fglrx driver has failed. The screen is now frozen in striate. Sometimes it does not turn on and reset take a black screen.

2- Next to installation the software center not opened.

3- I tried to install again. This time playing with compiz-manager broken. Opened one more desktop wallpaper, and it seems only. Desktop does not seem.

4- encrypted home folder and I saw the extreme performance issues.

***12.04 version of Ubuntu is very unstable and constantly freezes, crashes. AMD-ATI-based computer to use in particular is terrible.***

I had to install Debian now. In the meantime, while the installation of hard-disks are perceived too late.

Most importantly, does not working error-reporting programs. Unable to send a bug report.

Programs that failed version of Ubuntu, 12.04;

1. Compiz Fusion (so crashed and does not stable)
2. Home Encrypting Program (so slow)
3. Amd-Ati Driver Poor Support (**particularly FGLRX awful)**
4. Too much stability problem
5. Error reporting does not working programs
6. 5:10 Unity unstable

How can I report problems I have ubuntu team ?
Thank you.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: Im also experiencing horrible fglrx stability&&performance on 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

You can report bugs to Launchpad, but are these really bugs? Please can you tell us if you are new to Ubuntu, and then we can guide you further. From what you have said I would suggest you try to install the previous version of Ubuntu, 11.10, which is very stable indeed. But don't give up!

Update 8th May: I think everyone here will sympathise with you and your problems, but in defence of Ubuntu and the great bunch of guys working FREE to bring it to us, Ubuntu 12.04 is still a little guy, and so it is best not to jump the gun; as with the previous versions of Ubuntu, the team will try to iron out problems. I would strongly suggest that you go back to version 11.10 for a few months, and then upgrade when things have settled down more. Please don't desert Ubuntu, please support it for what it is.

Comment: Yes are these really bugs :(
I am not a new user. I used more than before Ubuntu. But the final version is too unstable. Compiz crashes and system freezes. Amd-Ati arch and ubuntu not stable.
I've heard not work very well with gnome 3 Fglrx. I use unity. But unity 5.10 based on gnome 3. Vesa driver is open source is insufficient.

Thank you for your attention but i'm really tired :/

Comment: @Sun Dial: I also second the stability problems with 12.04, constant crashing.  for me it's often after touching gtk3.4 applications.  I asked a question, not expecting an answer...  it seems like the really tough questions always become tumbleweeds.

Answer (score 0):

Most errors stem from compiz and unity 5.10.
The previous version did not work due to encoding software center (utf-8).
Interestingly, each installation of a problem in anything else. Software Center, Compiz, Unity, Bug Report, GPU, Ati FGLRX, Black screen, strip strip screen..

Are there problems with extreme stability on Amd arch. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS amd64. with Ati GPU (FGLRX driver).

I think the most important source of the problem is missing the installer to make installation. Not Better check for Installer. Installer Development should. How is the version the same..